# Bother with Grid on New App for IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I'm designing a new internal web app that has to support IE11 (as well as Chrome and Firefox). I love doing layouts in Grid, but having to figure out how to make any but the simplest work in IE11 can be a pain. Should I use CSS Grid and ms- prefixes, or avoid the headache and just pass on Grid for this one?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: If you deiced to go with Grid you will have more work to do. But it is doable as @raina77ow wrote you could use -ms- prefixs and make a IE friendly version of you App. You will not get the exact same stuff but it can work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Where else would you suggest I post to get the chance of feedback from pros who have the experience to help think through this kind of thing? I agree it "requires discussion" but unfortunately I don't have anyone to discuss this thing with at my work.

Comment: Unfortunately, SE does not have a place for questions that require discussion or opinions. Perhaps Reddit? There's no harm in using CSS-Grid **provided** yo have fallbacks in place for non-supporting browsers...but that's true of any CSS. Pages **do not have to look the same in all browsers**.

Comment: That's right, Reddit **does** have more than just r/funny. Forgot for a sec. Thanks!

Comment: You can also ask around in chatrooms here on SO, but there's no guarantee that you will get a response (just like asking a question)

Answer (score 1):

In short, it highly depends on how your application looks like. [**This article**](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/) describes the problems you might face quite well - and I fully agree with the summary:

> If you are using Grid in a very simple way, and positioning items
>   rather than using auto-placement then the fact that grid exists in
>   Internet Explorer from version 10 could turn out very useful. You
>   could certainly use this in order to create a simpler layout for IE10
>   and up, once Grid is shipped in other browsers.
>
> However be aware that this is going to require some additional testing
>   and work, you are unlikely to be able to simply rely on Autoprefixer
>   to run and do the work for you. For example, if you have used auto
>   placement for any item and then don’t set a position using the -ms
>   properties, that item is going to stack up with any other unpositioned
>   items in the first grid cell.